# What is causing the letters to be "all capitalized" in the section and subsection created below?

Tags: titlesec

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Thistle3!30!}
\colorlet{framecolor}{PaleVioletRed3}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.45}

\newenvironment{frshaded*}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\FrameRule\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] %
{\color{PaleVioletRed4}\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries\FrameSep 20pt\FrameRule=3pt}
{}
{0pt} % was 3pt
{\begin{frshaded*}\chaptername\hspace{3.6pt}\thechapter\kern8pt#1\end{frshaded*}\vskip-0.8ex\color{framecolor} \titlerule[1.2pt]}


\newcommand\Bheadfont{\fontsize{12pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\section}[hang] %
{\normalfont\scshape\color{darkblue}\Large\colorlet{shadecolor}{LightSteelBlue2!25!}\colorlet{framecolor}{darkblue} \FrameRule=1pt}
{}
{0pt}{\begin{frshaded*}\thesection\hskip0.618em\Bheadfont#1\end{frshaded*}}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang] %
{\normalfont\scshape\color{darkblue}\colorlet{shadecolor}{LightSteelBlue2!25!}\colorlet{framecolor}{darkblue} \FrameRule=1pt\FrameSep=6pt}
{}
{0pt}{\begin{frshaded*}\thesubsection\hskip0.618em#1\end{frshaded*}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a framed chapter}

\section{This is a framed section}

\subsection{This is a framed sub section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have specified `\scshape` that is caps and small caps

Comment: @user24039: -1 = zero research effort.

Answer (score 5):

You have specified `\scshape` that is *caps and small caps*.